# Binarysearch in sml

Tags: binary-tree, sml

```
datatype 'a tree= Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree

 fun binSearch (Node(left,n,right)) x =
    if x > n then false  
    else if x=n then true 
    else binSearch (Node(left,n,right)) x = binSearch (right) x andalso binSearch (left) x;
```

I'm helpless. What's wrong with that code? 
BTW it works for:

```
binSearch (Node (Node (Leaf 1, 2, Leaf 3), 4, Leaf 7)) 7;
```

and doesn't work for:

```
binSearch (Node (Node (Leaf 1, 2, Leaf 3), 4, Leaf 7)) 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of a binary tree isn't ideal, since (for example) you can't construct a tree with two elements. A more flexible and generally simpler definition is

```
datatype 'a tree = Leaf | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
```

where `Leaf` is a tree with no elements. This lets you write very simple base cases:

```
fun binSearch t x =
  case t of
    Leaf => false
  | Node (left, n, right) => ...
```

For the `Node` case, you might find it helpful to structure your code according to the three possibilities of comparing the the desired value `x` to the current value `n`.

```
fun binSearch t x =
  case t of
    Leaf => false
  | Node (left, n, right) =>
      case Int.compare (x, n) of
        LESS => ...
      | EQUAL => true
      | GREATER => ...
```

I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

In the first condition, you're saying that no elements smaller than `x` exist in any tree.

You forgot to write a case for the empty tree, which is the only case where you know whether a value definitely isn't found:

```
binSearch (Leaf n) x = n = x
```

Also, your last `else`,

```
binSearch (Node(left,n,right)) x = binSearch (right) x andalso binSearch (left) x
```

is a comparison of whether `binSearch (Node(left,n,right)) x` gives the same result as `binSearch right x andalso binSearch left x`.
That is, it says that `x` is found in the tree if it's either in the entire tree *and* both its subtrees, or not found anywhere at all.

The recursion should go

- If `x` is the value `n` in the node, we've found it.
  Otherwise,

  - If `x < n`, recurse into the left subtree,
  - If `x > n`, recurse into the right subtree

Implementation left as an exercise.